# Quelle différence entre « ce n'est pas » et « c'est pas » ?

Tags: négation

Quelle est la différence entre

> c'est pas...

et

> ce n'est pas...

Je pensais qu'une négation avait toujours besoin de « ne » et « pas ».

Comment: Il y a quelques problèmes dans ta formulation : *between* = *entre* ; *je pensais* (imparfait) ou *j'ai pensé* (passé composé) (*je pensais* est le meilleur choix possible dans ce cas) ; *négation* (*dénégation* signifie *denial*) ; *to need* = *avoir besoin de* donc il manque le verbe *avoir* avant *besoin* ; *toujours* serait plutôt positionné ailleurs dans la phrase : *Je pensais qu'une négation avait toujours besoin de "ne" et "pas".* Let us know if you prefer an answer in English (we tend to answer in French when the question is in French).

Comment: Merci beaucoup!! Non, en français, c'est parfait. Je dois apprendre cela et je l'ai compris. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Ce n'est pas

... est la forme correcte.

> C'est pas

... est une forme du langage courant qu'il ne faut surtout pas utiliser à l'écrit (dans un cadre professionnel ou scolaire). En revanche, à l'oral, presque personne ne dit le "ne", et ça paraît même étrange quand quelqu'un le dit.

Comment: Merci! "presque personne ne dit le 'ne' ". Est-ce que tu sais si c'est la même en Quebecois?

Comment: @HelloWorld Je suis presque sûr que oui.

Comment: @HelloWorld Je suis Québécois et je confirme, on omet souvent le "ne" à l'oral, sauf lorsqu'il y a beaucoup d'autres mots entre le verbe et le "pas". Exemple: Je suis pas fier de toi. Tu n'as encore une fois pas fait ce qu'on t'a demandé.